# Dummy Task for the Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I am writing some integration tests for a C# wrapper round the Window Task Scheduler: [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler)

Can someone suggest a suitable dummy application that I can call from the scheduled task. E.g. an app that will run silently. I can then check that it ran OK.

I did think of any empty batch file, but then I would have to ensure it was present on the server running the integration tests, before starting the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I tried

`cmd.exe /c exit`

which launches the command window and then closes it down. This seems to work OK. Open to any other suggestions though.